# What is the impact of using static variables in a Unity WebGL multiplayer project

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am creating a unity WebGL multiplayer game in which I move data across scenes using a static field and also hold the players info in a Scene using a static variable. I wanted to know if this would affect other instances of the game running on players browser (would they all shared that static variable) or the static variable be limited to its own instance of the game ?

Answer (score 3):

Each instance of the game will have its own variables.

#### Explanation

From [the docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-gettingstarted.html),

> To run in WebGL, all code needs to be JavaScript.

Simply put, your game is simply a web application. Like all web applications, it is constrained to it's own instance, unless through the use of local storage or setting of cookies.

Comment: it actually would make no difference whatever the application type. Static is not persistent, it is stored in the RAM and once the app is killed, all is lost.

Comment: @Everts thats okay, I think I can handle it...i just didn't want an instance where I store a players name in a static variable and all the other instances of the game running have their own player name changed to, just cause I am using static.

Comment: This indeed no. If you got the game running on two computers, those are two distinct applications and each gets its own static. So you safe on that issue.